# React Redux Saga with Typescript error property does not exist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

Setting up a React, Next js  app with TS for the first time and getting a beating at it.

TS throws below error on `redux-saga` set up:

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Input | DataPostGreeting | ErrorPostGreeting'.
> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'DataPostGreeting'

It's accurate that `name` does not exist on type `DataPostGreeting`, which is the type of the successful response, but it does exist in `Input`

The action in question is a POST to create a greeting on a test app.

I thought I had properly typed the payload as `Input` which is the `name` of the greeting, but TS does not seem happy with that. Even though it does recognizes  `Input`  as part of the applicable types.

This is the saga with the error trigger highlighted:

`/store/sagas/greetings.ts`

```
import { all, call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { actionPostGreetingOk, actionPostGreetingError } from '../actions/creators';
import { Actions } from '../actions/names';
import { ActionTypes } from '../actions/types';
import { apiQl } from 'lib/functions';

function* postGreeting(action: ActionTypes) {
  const queryQl = `mutation createGreeting(
    $name: String!
  ) {
      createGreeting(input: {
          name: $name
      }) {
          greeting {
              id
          }
      }
  }`;


  const variables = {
     name: action.payload.name,        // *** ERROR IS THROWN HERE ***
  };


  try {
    const data = yield call(apiQl, queryQl, variables);
    if (data.errors) {
        yield put(
            actionPostGreetingError({
                error: data.errors,
            }),
        );
    } else {
        yield put(
            actionPostGreetingOk({
                greeting: data.data.createGreeting,
            }),
        );
    }
} catch (error) {
    if (error.response === undefined || error.code === 'ECONNABORTED') {
        console.log('ERROR RESPONSE UNDEFINED, ABORTED');
    }
}

export default function* greeting() {
   yield all([takeLatest(Actions.POST_GREETING, postGreeting)]);
}
```

On the types file:

```
...
export interface Input {
   name: string;
}
export interface ActionPostGreeting {
   type: typeof Actions.POST_GREETING;
   payload: Input;
}
...

export type ActionTypes =
  | ActionPostGreeting
  | ActionPostGreetingInit
  | ActionPostGreetingOk
  | ActionPostGreetingError
  | ActionHydrate;
```

The action creator:

```
export const actionPostGreeting = (payload: Input): ActionPostGreeting => {
  return {
    type: Actions.POST_GREETING,
    payload,
 };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the whole `ActionTypes` union to your saga, but your function should only take a specific payload type (e.g. `ActionPostGreeting`). Otherwise it means your saga could be called with any payload, to fix your issue you can restrict the type like this:

```js
function* postGreeting(action: ActionPostGreeting) {
  // do stuff

  const variables = {
    name: action.payload.name, // will be good
  };
}
```